# Use TO_CHAR function to display the Fiscal Year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Is there a way in ORACLE that can display the Fiscal Year?

For example, I can write this query in SQL SERVER to pull the FYs but don't know how to write it in ORACLE.

```
SELECT
DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(mm, 3, DATE)) AS FY
FROM MYTABLE
```

Output:

```
FY
----
2009
2010
2011
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advise next time.

Comment: guess what, you could follow the advice *this* time! It's never too late :)

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle equivalent of your query would be something like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(MYDATE, 3)) AS FY
FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: If you want to be totally standards compliant, use *EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mydate + INTERVAL '3' MONTH)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(MYDATE, 3),'YYYY') fy FROM MYTABLE
```

Is probably the same